# Yotube like comment-Show link over textarea when user try to add a comment

Tags: asp.net, jquery, html, css, youtube

I'm working on asp.net application.And i'm looking for a way to show a link over a textarea when a user try to add a comment if the user is not loggd in.

I've got this idea from Youtube videos comments.If ur not coonected,they show a link saying u have to login to be able to add a comment.

Does anyone has an idea how to do that.a piece of jquery code will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards,
Rachid

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with an overlay link that you placed over the textarea on [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/).  Then it would just be a matter of hiding it on [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/):

**HTML**

```
<div id="comment">
    <textarea rows="3" cols="20"></textarea>
    <a class="overlay" href="" style="display: none; position: absolute;">You must login</a>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#comment').mouseenter(function() {
    var textarea = $(this).find('textarea');
    var overlay = $(this).find('.overlay');

    var pos = textarea.position();
    overlay.css({
        top: pos.top,
        left: pos.left,
        width: textarea.width(),
        height: textarea.height(),
        display: 'block'
    });
});

$('#comment').mouseleave(function() {
    var overlay = $(this).find('.overlay');
    overlay.css({
        display: 'none'
    });
});
```

You can see it [in action here](http://jsfiddle.net/eL742/1/).